# nUnit c# - Getting a c++ related exception when trying to debug a test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have the exact same problem as this guy: http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/9192562e-b875-411f-9a95-9150ebc157b4?category=vsunittest

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.**CppUnitTestFramework**.ComInterfaces

This is a .net project. No Cpp anywhere.

Running the test normally runs fine or just hitting continue a few times will make the test debug fine.

I am using the latest nunit and nunit test adapter version together with .net 4.6.2 on Visual Studio 2017 Pro (also latest version).

Comment: You are apparently doing something to reference Microsoft TestTools, which you would not need in order to do nunit testing.

Comment: It's an empty project with only one class and nunit + testadapter....

Even after repairing VS, it still was not working. So I created a new project and now it works. Maybe the project was somehow corrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an empty project with only one class and nunit + testadapter.... Even after repairing VS, it still was not working. So I created a new project and now it works. Maybe the project was somehow corrupted.